# compiling 32 bit app on 64 bit machine to get 64 bit app

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, windows-7

I am using window 7 ultimate 64-bit operating system and I make app of 32-bit in this environment
now i want to convert that app from 32-bit to 64-bit

any help appreciated.

thanks

Comment: because my app uses qt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `BUILD` menu and choose `Configuration Manager`-

Here you could change your actual target platform from `x86` to `AnyCPU` or `x64`

This article (a bit old but still pertinent) [Visual Studio .NET Platform Target Explained](http://visualstudiohacks.com/articles/visual-studio-net-platform-target-explained/) details the differences between the option available

Comment: I did that but on compiling app giving error unable to open resource file and ui file

Comment: anyways i got to set platform from this